# Hive: Need to specify partition columns because the destination table is partitioned

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I'm wondering if it's possible in Hive to insert a non-partitioned table into one that *is* partitioned. The first table is as follows:

```
hive> describe extended user_ratings;
OK
userid                  int                                         
movieid                 int                                         
rating                  int                                         
unixtime                int                                         

Detailed Table Information  Table(tableName:user_ratings, dbName:ml, owner:cloudera, createTime:1500142667, lastAccessTime:0, retention:0, sd:StorageDescriptor(cols:[FieldSchema(name:userid, type:int, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:movieid, type:int, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:rating, type:int, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:unixtime, type:int, comment:null)], location:hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/ml.db/user_ratings, inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat, outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat, compressed:false, numBuckets:-1, serdeInfo:SerDeInfo(name:null, serializationLib:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, parameters:{serialization.format=    , field.delim=
Time taken: 0.418 seconds, Fetched: 6 row(s)
```

The new table is thus:

```
hive> describe extended rating_buckets;
OK
userid                  int                                         
movieid                 int                                         
rating                  int                                         
unixtime                int                                         
genre                   string                                      

# Partition Information      
# col_name              data_type               comment             

genre                   string                                      

Detailed Table Information  Table(tableName:rating_buckets, dbName:default, owner:cloudera, createTime:1500506879, lastAccessTime:0, retention:0, sd:StorageDescriptor(cols:[FieldSchema(name:userid, type:int, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:movieid, type:int, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:rating, type:int, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:unixtime, type:int, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:genre, type:string, comment:null)], location:hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/rating_buckets, inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat, outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat, compressed:false, numBuckets:8, serdeInfo:SerDeInfo(name:null, serializationLib:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, parameters:{serialization.format=  , field.delim=
Time taken: 0.46 seconds, Fetched: 12 row(s)
```

It seems to be counting the partition ("genre") as being the same as the other columns...did I maybe create it wrong?

Anyways, here's what happens when I try to do an INSERT OVERWRITE into the new table:

```
hive> FROM ml.user_ratings
    > INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE rating_buckets
    > select userid, movieid, rating, unixtime;
FAILED: SemanticException 2:23 Need to specify partition columns because the destination table is partitioned. Error encountered near token 'rating_buckets'
```

Should I just recreate the first table with a partition? Is there a way to copy the first table over and leave the partition untouched?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You aren't even including genre in your select list.  I think it needs to be last in your select.  You can't partition by nothing.

You also need to specify the partitioning with the table, like so:

```
insert overwrite table ratings_buckets partition(genre)
select
userid,
movieid,
rating,
unixtime,
<SOMETHING> as genre
from
...
```

Comment: I appreciate your input, but unfortunately, it returns the following:

hive> insert overwrite table rating_buckets partition(genre)
    > select
    > userid,
    > movieid,
    > rating,
    > unixtime,
    > (action) as genre
    > from ml.user_ratings;
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 7:1 Invalid table alias or column reference 'action': (possible column names are: userid, movieid, rating, unixtime)

Comment: Are you trying to insert the word action as your genre?  If so, you need to surround it with single quotes, not parens:  `'action' as genre`.